# Unable to load angularjs on demo

Tags: angularjs, github, drag-and-drop

[image]I am trying to run drag and drop library of angular.js from https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists. But after downlaoding the code from github, i am unable to play the demo. I am extracting the folder and just playing the simple html page. I am unable to find the problem. Can anyone help!

Comment: Do you get any error messages? More precisely what do you mean by "unable to play the demo" ?

Comment: I think i am unable to laod angular.js. Only plain html is loading.

Comment: See attached snap shot.

Comment: open developer console of the chrome. you will see the error there

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem. I was trying to open without any server. I then open in visual studio. It works.